# How to call external CSS and JS in AMP using ASP.NET (ASPX) and C#

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amp-html

How to call external CSS and JS in AMP using ASP.NET (ASPX) and C#?

Please help me for finding the both the tag JS and CSS to call externally.

I have done the Internal style sheet its say long term.

Comment: According to https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec external JS is not allowed. As to CSS, "One additional style tag is allowed in head tag for the purpose of custom styling. This style tag must have the attribute `amp-custom`"

Comment: if external css and js are not  allowed then how the big website which are there how they are maintaining their css and js file to reduce the load time

Comment: I run a site which has 5000+ pages. By now I `AMP`ify some 700 pages. To do it I rewrote 3 (three) `.aspx` pages and one `.master` page. I put into `style amp-custom` only what the page (template) requires.

Answer (score 1):

In short, *all* CSS **must** be inline as per the AMP HTML Specification, and JavaScript is **not** allowed.

However, you could potentially work around this with Progressive Web App (PWA) behaviour, [as demonstrated at Google I/O 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xF6mjl-wOqU&t=12m30s) by Paul Bakaus.

**Resources:**

- [AMP HTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#stylesheets)
- [AMP by Example: amp-install-serviceworker](https://www.ampbyexample.com/components/amp-install-serviceworker)